# Increase Date datatype by Number

Tags: sql, date, sql-update

I am trying update a column called `scheddate`, which is a `Date` datatype, based on the value from another column, `transleadtime`.

`transleadtime` holds the number of minutes as a `Number` datatype.

What is the best way to add minutes to a date variable? Here is what I have tried so far:

```
  'UPDATE scpomgr.schedrcpts sr
      SET sr.scheddate = (SELECT sr.scheddate + MAX(n.transleadtime / 1440)
     FROM scpomgr.network n
    WHERE n.source = sr.loc);'
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors right now? What are you receiving?

Comment: Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use the [dateadd](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp) function here. This function takes a specific value, and adds it to a specified date. You can add days, years, minutes, hours, and so on. In your case, you want to add minutes, and since you are adding to the already existing scheddate, you will use that as a parameter.

Here's what the syntax may look like:

```
UPDATE scpomgr.schedrcpts sr
SET sr.scheddate = dateadd(
                        minute, 
                        (SELECT n.transleadtime FROM scpomgr.network n WHERE n.source = sr.loc),
                        (SELECT sr.scheddate)
                   );
```

This will add minutes (specified by the first parameter), to the sr.scheddate (specified by the third parameter). The minutes that will be added are the n.translead time (specified by the second parameter).

Right now, this makes the assumption that selecting the sr.scheddate and select n.transleadtime that you have will only return 1 value. If they return more, you may have to adjust your where statement or limit the result set.

I also took out the NVL function, but if you want to protect against null values I would put them in the second and/or third parameters. Definitely in the second, but if your scheddate column doesn't accept null values, then you won't need it.

```
UPDATE scpomgr.schedrcpts sr
SET sr.scheddate = dateadd(
                        minute, 
                        NVL((SELECT n.transleadtime FROM scpomgr.network n WHERE n.source = sr.loc), 0),
                        (SELECT sr.scheddate)
                   );
```

I can't test this at the moment, so it may take some tweaking, but start there and let me know how we can improve it.

**EDIT**

If you're looking for the highest transleadtime, I do think the MAX function would be the simplest way. Try adjusting the subquery in the second parameter to:

```
SELECT MAX(n.transleadtime) FROM scpomgr.network n WHERE n.source = sr.loc
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  However I need it to return an actual date for sr.schedrcpts.  Basically, I looking to Update Sr.SchedRcpt by adding the highest value for n.transleadtime Where sr.loc = n.source.  That highest Leadtime will be added to the scheddate date.  Can I still use datedd() for this?   I believe I will need to add some type of Max() in this statement as well

Comment: Yes, I think the MAX() method would be the cleanest way to get the value you wanted. See my edit. Hopefully we can work through this one, I'm curious to see the solution.

Comment: UPDATE scpomgr.schedrcpts sr
SET sr.scheddate = dateadd(day, 
                          (SELECT MAX(n.transleadtime)/1440 FROM scpomgr.network n WHERE n.source = sr.loc), sr.scheddate);

Running this I get an 'Invalid Identifier' error.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Not yet. Do you mind telling me what the columns are for each of those two tables? When I have some time later this evening I will try to recreate this.